# Terminal command to show Network Interfaces that are NOT CONNECTED

Tags: linux, networking, terminal

- Using terminal mode I want to display the current network interfaces that are NOT CONNECTED on my computer.
- I have used `ifconfig` to find the connected interfaces along with their IP-address but can't figure out how to display just those that are NOT CONNECTED.

Comment: `ifconfig -a` shows *all* network interfaces, connected or not

Comment: With "not connected" you mean "cable not plugged in" or "deactivated"?

Answer (score 3):

You can just do:

```
$ ip link show
```

for a list of interfaces including their status.  You can filter results for devices that are not in use by piping `grep DOWN` after the `ip` command:

```
$ ip link show | grep DOWN
```

Comment: Not connected is not the same as down.

Answer (score 2):

```
ip link show |
awk '/^[1-9]/ && $0 !~ "LOWER_UP" { inf=$2; sub(":","",inf); print inf; }' |
while read iface; do
    [[ $(readlink /sys/class/net/$iface) =~ devices/virtual ]] || echo $iface
done
```

The first part (`ip link show | awk`) gets all the interfaces for which the L2 driver reports that they are connected. The second part discards all virtual interfaces because "not connected" does not mean much for them.

Answer (score 1):

Using `ifconfig` (because that's the command you said you know how to use) and `bash` with `diff` and `sed`:

```
diff <( ifconfig ) <( ifconfig -a ) | sed -nE 's/^> ([^[:blank:]]+).*/\1/p'
```

This will compare the output of `ifconfig` with that of `ifconfig -a`.  From that output, any line starting with `>` (signifying that they are only in the `ifconfig -a` output) will be relating to interfaces that are not "UP".  The `sed` expression parses out the interface names.

The result will be a list of interfaces that are not up.

---

The `sed` expression `s/^> ([^[:blank:]]+).*/\1/p`:

This is a substitution.  It will match any line starting with `>` followed by a space.  After that, it will capture any non-blank string of characters.  This, with the rest of the line, is then replaced with the captured string of non-blank characters and the result is printed.  The only lines that matches the regular expression in the output from `diff` are lines that mentions the interface name at the start of the line after `>` and space.

Comment: Thank you all! much appreciated! Kusalananda had the best answer for me.

Comment: Not connected is not the same as down. `ifconfig` [is deprecated](https://serverfault.com/a/633229/407820).

Answer (score 1):

You can check the state of the network interface from `/sys/class/net/$interface/carrier` file. (`1` = connetcted , `0` = disconnected)

To get the disconnected network interface:

```bsh
for i in $( ls /sys/class/net );do 
    if grep -q 0 /sys/class/net/$i/carrier; then
        echo $i; 
    fi
done
```

Comment: I'm not sure why I get errors like `grep: /sys/class/net/lo/carrier: No such file or directory` in all cases. Doesn't seem a quote/escape issue. Works outside the `if`.

Comment: No need to invoke `ls` in a subshell, just do `for i in /sys/class/net/*; do …`